# gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated

Tags: scala, curl, keystore, akka-http, gnutls

I'm writing a simple akka-http webserver with Scala. I want to establish a TLS connection (webserver authentication) with a curl. I'm following the documentation reachable [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/server-https-support.html) . I've first created a certificate and a key for webserver (verified by rootCA.pem created previously), and then I've converted it to a keystore file webserver.ks following this [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35976_01/server.740/es_admin/src/tadm_ssl_convert_pem_to_jks.html). The webserver seems starting correctly but when I do a curl like that:

> curl -i -v -XGET "https://localhost:9090/ready" --cacert rootCA.pem -k

I see this error:

```
    Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9090 (#0)
    found 1 certificates in rootCA.pem
    found 597 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
    ALPN, offering http/1.1
    gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
    Closing connection 0
    curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

I've tried to start webserver also without TLS and it performs without any problem.

How can I solve this?

Comment: did you solved it ?

Comment: I have seen such an issue with FileZilla on EC2.
The problem was that FileZilla requires additional open ports to operate. Enabling it in AWS security groups solved the issue.